# Expand indexes on Structure Tab by default

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am wondering if it is possible to expand the indexes by default by adding something to the config.inc.php file.

This is how it looks by default:

[image: This is how it looks by default:]

This is what it looks like when expanded. I want this by default
[image: This is what it looks like when expanded. I want this by default]

In earlier versions of phpMyAdmin the indexes-table was visible without expanding it manually. So I think there is an option for that but I couldn't find it in the docs.